# How to use CSS to show or hide toggle link for panel collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a link in my panel-heading that controls the collapse to the panel-body. I also have a page wide collapse toggle for all panel-body's. So I cant use one variable to target them all. I have my CSS setup to hide the appropriate arrow like this...

```
div[aria-expanded="false"] + .panel-heading .fa-angle-up {
    display: none;
}
div[aria-expanded="true"] + .panel-heading .fa-angle-down{
    display: none;
}
```

This works and correctly hides or shows the up or down arrow based on whether or not the panel body is collapsed. However, it does not work on initial page load, only once the toggle is clicked it will work from that point forward. Why is this?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myPanel">
        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
    </a>
</div>
 <div id="myPanel" class="panel-body collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
    Test
 </div>
```

Comment: I believe you will need to provide a default CSS for the initial load. The arrow that needs to be hidden should be given inline css display none. Once you start clicking on the elements, then the css should take over. 

I can help you further if you can provide a working prototype of your layout, so i can provide a specific solution.

Comment: Interesting enough if I apply inline style for the down arrow as display:none - then that arrow never shows up. I'll try put together a code pen this afternoon.